# Possible to copy the presentation details of one item to another?

Tags: presentation

From the content editor, is it possible to copy the presentation details, renderings, layout, etc.. from Item A and paste onto Item B?

I'd like to avoid creating a duplicate of A and then resetting the content field values manually.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the presentation values of Item A are stored as an XML construct in the raw values of the Renderings field.

You can see that field here:
[image]

If you follow the blue arrows and click on Raw Values you'll see:

[image]

**Raw Values Method**

Select the rendering field value, copy, and then in **Item B**, do the same thing, but *PASTE* the field value there.

Turn off Raw Values, and you should see the presentation on both Items now.

**Editor Method**

You can also use the *Copy To* dialogue as well.  Which has been there forever, and I always forget about it.

[image]

> **SPECIAL NOTE**
>
> While this is the direct answer to your question, there is an
>   architectural viewpoint that must be considered. Generally, adjusting
>   presentation on *Items* directly is frown upon, because you break the
>   association that it might have with the Template Standard Values that
>   the Item derives from.
>
> In those cases, generally you only muck with **Final Renderings** on
>   the item itself, and **Renderings** on the Template Standard Values
>   that the Item is made from.
>
> For more information on that, take a peek at Sitecore's documentation
>   on [editing the layout of an item](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/creating_and_editing_items/editing/edit_the_layout_of_an_item).

Comment: Note that you can use this technique on _Standard Values items too, and you can use it to copy Shared Layout details to Final Layout and vice versa

Comment: This way of working is also useful is you want to copy to multiple target items. You could script this stuff...

Comment: "This way" is the raw values way.. apparently Pete added others to his answer :)

Comment: I like pictures.

Answer (score 15):

Yes. Open the presentation details of the item you want to copy from. you will see a link "Copy To" beside "Edit". You can pick which target devices you want and to which item you want to copy the presentation details

Comment: First time I've ever noticed that button there. Thanks.

Comment: If that is what you were looking for please mark your question as answered. thanks

Comment: OMG, how did I completely miss that all these years?!

Answer (score 10):

If you have Sitecore Powershell Extensions installed then [there is an OOTB module](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/) available to copy/paste renderings between items.

Simply right click the item, then select `Scripts > Layout > Copy Renderings` and then select the `Paste Rendering` option on the item you want to copy to.

[image: Copy Renderings]